# Customize tfs lab deployment running account other than nt authority\system

Tags: tfs

We are recently developing TFS bdt with complex environment which contains domain controller.

That means each environment will have its own dns server and owner domain. They will share connections with their inner domain account.

Also our product should be installed by inner domain account, not build in account "nt authority\system".
Because "nt authority\system" could not access shared location between each nodes.

But after testing with lab deployment script, it will always use "nt authority\system" as default.

Even I have changed test agent running account to "domain\user".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search and investigation, we found that if we can change following services running account to expected user, then tfs lab bdt deployment script will run with expected account, other than **nt authority\system**.

[image]

ref post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f46dc491-87c2-4234-8566-99b25302020e/deployment-tasks-run-under-nt-authoritysystem?forum=tfsbuild